# How to parse/unescape/decode this kind of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

One site is using XHR requests to get back data like this(string response):

```
$('#point').html('\
  \
    <div class=\"lake\" data-size=\"I\" 
  // more similar code
```

I am trying to extract and convert this to proper HTML.

First I removed the jQuery part(string split) then I tried using js `unescape()`, jQuerys `parseHtml()`, custom function:

```
function htmlDecode(input)
{
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

Nothing corrently parses this. Any idea what kind of encoding/escape system it looks like they are using and how do I reverse this?

Comment: The string in the html() call would be a javascript string, so eval() or parse as a JSON string (keep the quotes).

Comment: Half a line of code is not really representative. Can you give us a little more. The end of the data returned is probably also significant in terms of trialing delimiters so please include that as well

Comment: eval() did it, thank you!!!

Comment: eval is pretty risky. it will run javascript code that is from maybe an unreliable source. If you can use JSON.parse it is better.